# Oracle slow connect by prior query on Oracle 11g ContentDB

Tags: oracle

We have the following query against Oracle Content DB on an Oracle 11.2.0.4.0.
This query takes awfully long, 56s.

Do you have any starting points on how to optimize/further analyze it?
The query runs in <2s if the database is idle and the query is run for a second time. Table publicobjects contains about 140 million rows.
Indexes have been rebuilt.

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT     main_object.id, 
                         main_object.classid, 
                         main_object.name, 
                         main_object.createdate, 
                         main_object.lastmodifydate, 
                         main_object_creator.name         AS creator_name, 
  ...some fields omitted
              FROM       ( 
                                SELECT odm_publicobject.id, 
                                       odm_publicobject.classid, 
                                       odm_publicobject.name, 
                                       odm_publicobject.createdate, 
                                       odm_publicobject.lastmodifydate, 
                                       odm_publicobject.creator, 
                                       odm_publicobject.lastmodifier 
                                FROM   odm_publicobject 
                                WHERE  odm_publicobject.classid IN (:"SYS_B_0", 
                                                                    :"SYS_B_1") 
                                       START WITH odm_publicobject.id = :id 
                                       CONNECT BY PRIOR odm_publicobject.id = odm_publicobject.primaryparentfolder ) main_object
              left join  odm_publicobject main_object_creator 
              ON         main_object.creator = main_object_creator.id 
              left join  odm_publicobject main_object_lastmodifier 
              ON         main_object.lastmodifier = main_object_lastmodifier.id 
              left join  ( (odm_category c_207214ah 
              inner join odm_207214ah c_207214ah_data 
              ON         c_207214ah.id = c_207214ah_data.id) 
              left join  odm_publicobject c_207214ah_data_207221_res 
              ON         c_207214ah_data.custom_207221=c_207214ah_data_207221_res.id ) 
              ON         c_207214ah.associatedpublicobject = main_object.id 
              left join  ( (odm_category c_751741ah 
              inner join odm_751741ah c_751741ah_data 
              ON         c_751741ah.id = c_751741ah_data.id) ) 
              ON         c_751741ah.associatedpublicobject = main_object.id 
              left join  ( (odm_category c_207004ah 
              inner join odm_207004ah c_207004ah_data 
              ON         c_207004ah.id = c_207004ah_data.id) 
              left join  odm_publicobject c_207004ah_data_207016_res 
              ON         c_207004ah_data.custom_207016=c_207004ah_data_207016_res.id ) 
              ON         c_207004ah.associatedpublicobject = main_object.id;
```

Trace File:

```
    *** SESSION ID:(596.44464) 2018-02-09 19:03:13.135*** SESSION ID:               (596.44464) 2018-02-09 19:03:13.135

           CLOSE #4859769072:c=11,e=29,dep=0,type=1,tim=14609929264242
           =====================
           PARSING IN CURSOR #4860378880 len=5262 dep=0 uid=51 oct=3 lid=51 tim=14609929265275 hv=4208239032 ad='7000107c9e5f008' sqlid='dcw1m6vxd98ds'
           select count(*) from (
           SELECT    main_object.ID,    main_object.CLASSID,    main_object.NAME,    main_object.CREATEDATE,    main_object.LASTMODIFYDATE,    main_object_creator.NAME as creator_name,    main_object_lastmodifier.NAME as lastmodifier_name   ,   c_207214ah_data.ID AS c_207214ah_id   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207215 AS c_207214ah_data_207215   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207220 AS c_207214ah_data_207220   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207219 AS c_207214ah_data_207219   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207218 AS c_207214ah_data_207218   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207225 AS c_207214ah_data_207225   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207216 AS c_207214ah_data_207216   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207226 AS c_207214ah_data_207226   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207217 AS c_207214ah_data_207217   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207222 AS c_207214ah_data_207222   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207221 AS c_207214ah_data_207221   ,   c_207214ah_data_207221_res.NAME AS c_207214ah_data_207221_name   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207224 AS c_207214ah_data_207224   ,   c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207223 AS c_207214ah_data_207223   ,   c_751741ah_data.ID AS c_751741ah_id   ,   c_751741ah_data.CUSTOM_751742 AS c_751741ah_data_751742   ,   c_751741ah_data.CUSTOM_751746 AS c_751741ah_data_751746   ,   c_751741ah_data.CUSTOM_751745 AS c_751741ah_data_751745   ,   c_751741ah_data.CUSTOM_751744 AS c_751741ah_data_751744   ,   c_751741ah_data.CUSTOM_751747 AS c_751741ah_data_751747   ,   c_751741ah_data.CUSTOM_751743 AS c_751741ah_data_751743   ,   c_207004ah_data.ID AS c_207004ah_id   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_163755764 AS c_207004ah_data_163755764   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207033 AS c_207004ah_data_207033   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207018 AS c_207004ah_data_207018   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207005 AS c_207004ah_data_207005   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_326005166 AS c_207004ah_data_326005166   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207026 AS c_207004ah_data_207026   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207032 AS c_207004ah_data_207032   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207024 AS c_207004ah_data_207024   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207012 AS c_207004ah_data_207012   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_163755768 AS c_207004ah_data_163755768
           ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207029 AS c_207004ah_data_207029   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207016 AS c_207004ah_data_207016   ,   c_207004ah_data_207016_res.NAME AS c_207004ah_data_207016_name   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207027 AS c_207004ah_data_207027   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_163755760 AS c_207004ah_data_163755760   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207010 AS c_207004ah_data_207010   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207013 AS c_207004ah_data_207013   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207006 AS c_207004ah_data_207006   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_641304 AS c_207004ah_data_641304   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207025 AS c_207004ah_data_207025   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207017 AS c_207004ah_data_207017   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207022 AS c_207004ah_data_207022   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207028 AS c_207004ah_data_207028   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207021 AS c_207004ah_data_207021   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207030 AS c_207004ah_data_207030   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207023 AS c_207004ah_data_207023   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_163755766 AS c_207004ah_data_163755766   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207011 AS c_207004ah_data_207011   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207031 AS c_207004ah_data_207031   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207014 AS c_207004ah_data_207014   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207007 AS c_207004ah_data_207007   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207019 AS c_207004ah_data_207019   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207008 AS c_207004ah_data_207008   ,   c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207009 AS c_207004ah_data_207009    FROM (
           SELECT            odm_publicobject.ID,            odm_publicobject.CLASSID,            odm_publicobject.NAME,            odm_publicobject.CREATEDATE,            odm_publicobject.LASTMODIFYDATE,            odm_publicobject.CREATOR,            odm_publicobject.LASTMODIFIER        FROM odm_publicobject           WHERE odm_publicobject.classid in (:"SYS_B_0",:"SYS_B_1")   START WITH odm_publicobject.id = :id    CONNECT BY PRIOR odm_publicobject.id = odm_publicobject.primaryparentfolder    ) main_object        LEFT JOIN ODM_PUBLICOBJECT main_object_creator ON main_object.CREATOR = main_object_creator.id        LEFT JOIN ODM_PUBLICOBJECT main_object_lastmodifier ON main_object.LASTMODIFIER = main_object_lastmodifier.id          LEFT JOIN (       (ODM_CATEGORY c_207214ah INNER JOIN ODM_207214ah c_207214ah_data ON c_207214ah.ID = c_207214ah_data.ID)          LEFT JOIN odm_publicobject c_207214ah_data_207221_res ON c_207214ah_data.CUSTOM_207221=c_207214ah_data_207221_res.ID      ) ON c_207214ah.ASSOCIATEDPUBLICOBJECT = main_object.ID         LEFT JOIN (       (ODM_CATEGORY c_751741ah INNER JOIN ODM_751741ah c_751741ah_data ON c_751741ah.ID = c_751741ah_data.ID)   ) ON c_751741ah.ASSOCIATEDPUBLICOBJECT = main_object.ID         LEFT JOIN (       (ODM_CATEGORY c_207004ah INNER JOIN ODM_207004ah c_207004ah_data ON c_207004ah.ID = c_207004ah_data.ID)          LEFT JOIN odm_publicobject c_207004ah_data_207016_res ON c_207004ah_data.CUSTOM_207016=c_207004ah_data_207016_res.ID      ) ON c_207004ah.ASSOCIATEDPUBLICOBJECT = main_object.ID
           )
           END OF STMT
           PARSE #4860378880:c=332,e=951,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=2,plh=2750632795,tim=14609929265274
           EXEC #4860378880:c=32,e=90,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=2,plh=2750632795,tim=14609929265516

           *** 2018-02-09 19:04:09.924
           FETCH #4860378880:c=1216278,e=56786423,p=12055,cr=588614,cu=0,mis=0,r=1,dep=0,og=2,plh=2750632795,tim=14609986052048
           STAT #4860378880 id=1 cnt=1 pid=0 pos=1 obj=0 op='SORT AGGREGATE (cr=588614 pr=12055 pw=0 time=56786438 us)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=2 cnt=10719 pid=1 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=588614 pr=12055 pw=0 time=56673159 us cost=9 size=60129541948 card=14)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=3 cnt=10719 pid=2 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=167003 pr=9591 pw=0 time=37387310 us cost=8 size=60129542102 card=14)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=4 cnt=6372 pid=3 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=72931 pr=8116 pw=0 time=36748544 us cost=7 size=56 card=14)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=5 cnt=5304 pid=4 pos=1 obj=0 op='VIEW  (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10981326 us cost=8 size=182 card=14)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=6 cnt=5304 pid=5 pos=1 obj=0 op='FILTER  (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10979429 us)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=7 cnt=15434 pid=6 pos=1 obj=0 op='CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10958416 us)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=8 cnt=1 pid=7 pos=1 obj=48562 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_PUBLICOBJECT (cr=4 pr=3 pw=0 time=21937 us cost=2 size=27 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=9 cnt=1 pid=8 pos=1 obj=48563 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=3 pr=2 pw=0 time=15438 us cost=2 size=0 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=10 cnt=15433 pid=7 pos=2 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS  (cr=19726 pr=4338 pw=0 time=5586309 us cost=4 size=364 card=13)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=11 cnt=15434 pid=10 pos=1 obj=0 op='CONNECT BY PUMP  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=12493 us)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=12 cnt=15433 pid=10 pos=2 obj=48562 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_PUBLICOBJECT (cr=19726 pr=4338 pw=0 time=12094807 us cost=2 size=351 card=13)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=13 cnt=15433 pid=12 pos=1 obj=295311 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_288_UNI (cr=14576 pr=1323 pw=0 time=3902935 us cost=1 size=0 card=13)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=14 cnt=3158 pid=4 pos=2 obj=0 op='VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=53201 pr=3775 pw=0 time=20327698 us cost=1 size=5 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=15 cnt=3158 pid=14 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=53201 pr=3775 pw=0 time=20323411 us cost=4 size=10 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=16 cnt=3158 pid=15 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS  (cr=50007 pr=3754 pw=0 time=22060978 us cost=3 size=24 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=17 cnt=17036 pid=16 pos=1 obj=48662 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=18986 pr=2822 pw=0 time=18693902 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=18 cnt=17036 pid=17 pos=1 obj=48664 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=8328 pr=1107 pw=0 time=5986284 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=19 cnt=3158 pid=16 pos=2 obj=84010 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_207214AH (cr=31021 pr=932 pw=0 time=5870949 us cost=1 size=12 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=20 cnt=3158 pid=19 pos=1 obj=84011 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0018438 (cr=27863 pr=587 pw=0 time=3262235 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=21 cnt=3140 pid=15 pos=2 obj=48563 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=3194 pr=21 pw=0 time=197833 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=22 cnt=7896 pid=3 pos=2 obj=0 op='VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=94072 pr=1475 pw=0 time=6836424 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=23 cnt=7896 pid=22 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS  (cr=94072 pr=1475 pw=0 time=6829410 us cost=3 size=14 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=24 cnt=33338 pid=23 pos=1 obj=48662 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=34414 pr=850 pw=0 time=9746606 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=25 cnt=33338 pid=24 pos=1 obj=48664 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=9987 pr=5 pw=0 time=67429 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=26 cnt=7896 pid=23 pos=2 obj=94507 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0022056 (cr=59658 pr=625 pw=0 time=2693326 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=27 cnt=8429 pid=2 pos=2 obj=0 op='VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=421611 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16205841 us cost=1 size=3 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=28 cnt=8429 pid=27 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=421611 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16196537 us cost=4 size=6 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=29 cnt=8429 pid=28 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS  (cr=421597 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16165037 us cost=3 size=20 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=30 cnt=368542 pid=29 pos=1 obj=48662 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=136832 pr=410 pw=0 time=1367514 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=31 cnt=368542 pid=30 pos=1 obj=48664 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=11961 pr=3 pw=0 time=307670 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=32 cnt=8429 pid=29 pos=2 obj=83994 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_207004AH (cr=284765 pr=2054 pw=0 time=13222238 us cost=1 size=10 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=33 cnt=8429 pid=32 pos=1 obj=83995 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0018436 (cr=276275 pr=691 pw=0 time=4370618 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=34 cnt=0 pid=28 pos=2 obj=48563 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=14 pr=0 pw=0 time=15922 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)'
           FETCH #4860378880:c=1,e=1,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=0,plh=2750632795,tim=14609986053747
           *** SESSION ID:(596.44464) 2018-02-09 19:04:09.930
                  CLOSE #4859769072:c=11,e=29,dep=0,type=1,tim=14609929264242
           =====================
           PARSING IN CURSOR #4860378880 len=5262 dep=0 uid=51 oct=3 lid=51 tim=14609929265275 hv=4208239032 ad='7000107c9e5f008' sqlid='dcw1m6vxd98ds'
           select count(*) from (
           ....
           )
           END OF STMT
           PARSE #4860378880:c=332,e=951,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=2,plh=2750632795,tim=14609929265274
           EXEC #4860378880:c=32,e=90,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=2,plh=2750632795,tim=14609929265516

           *** 2018-02-09 19:04:09.924
           FETCH #4860378880:c=1216278,e=56786423,p=12055,cr=588614,cu=0,mis=0,r=1,dep=0,og=2,plh=2750632795,tim=14609986052048
           STAT #4860378880 id=1 cnt=1 pid=0 pos=1 obj=0 op='SORT AGGREGATE (cr=588614 pr=12055 pw=0 time=56786438 us)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=2 cnt=10719 pid=1 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=588614 pr=12055 pw=0 time=56673159 us cost=9 size=60129541948 card=14)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=3 cnt=10719 pid=2 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=167003 pr=9591 pw=0 time=37387310 us cost=8 size=60129542102 card=14)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=4 cnt=6372 pid=3 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=72931 pr=8116 pw=0 time=36748544 us cost=7 size=56 card=14)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=5 cnt=5304 pid=4 pos=1 obj=0 op='VIEW  (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10981326 us cost=8 size=182 card=14)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=6 cnt=5304 pid=5 pos=1 obj=0 op='FILTER  (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10979429 us)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=7 cnt=15434 pid=6 pos=1 obj=0 op='CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10958416 us)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=8 cnt=1 pid=7 pos=1 obj=48562 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_PUBLICOBJECT (cr=4 pr=3 pw=0 time=21937 us cost=2 size=27 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=9 cnt=1 pid=8 pos=1 obj=48563 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=3 pr=2 pw=0 time=15438 us cost=2 size=0 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=10 cnt=15433 pid=7 pos=2 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS  (cr=19726 pr=4338 pw=0 time=5586309 us cost=4 size=364 card=13)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=11 cnt=15434 pid=10 pos=1 obj=0 op='CONNECT BY PUMP  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=12493 us)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=12 cnt=15433 pid=10 pos=2 obj=48562 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_PUBLICOBJECT (cr=19726 pr=4338 pw=0 time=12094807 us cost=2 size=351 card=13)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=13 cnt=15433 pid=12 pos=1 obj=295311 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_288_UNI (cr=14576 pr=1323 pw=0 time=3902935 us cost=1 size=0 card=13)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=14 cnt=3158 pid=4 pos=2 obj=0 op='VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=53201 pr=3775 pw=0 time=20327698 us cost=1 size=5 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=15 cnt=3158 pid=14 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=53201 pr=3775 pw=0 time=20323411 us cost=4 size=10 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=16 cnt=3158 pid=15 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS  (cr=50007 pr=3754 pw=0 time=22060978 us cost=3 size=24 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=17 cnt=17036 pid=16 pos=1 obj=48662 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=18986 pr=2822 pw=0 time=18693902 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=18 cnt=17036 pid=17 pos=1 obj=48664 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=8328 pr=1107 pw=0 time=5986284 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=19 cnt=3158 pid=16 pos=2 obj=84010 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_207214AH (cr=31021 pr=932 pw=0 time=5870949 us cost=1 size=12 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=20 cnt=3158 pid=19 pos=1 obj=84011 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0018438 (cr=27863 pr=587 pw=0 time=3262235 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=21 cnt=3140 pid=15 pos=2 obj=48563 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=3194 pr=21 pw=0 time=197833 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=22 cnt=7896 pid=3 pos=2 obj=0 op='VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=94072 pr=1475 pw=0 time=6836424 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=23 cnt=7896 pid=22 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS  (cr=94072 pr=1475 pw=0 time=6829410 us cost=3 size=14 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=24 cnt=33338 pid=23 pos=1 obj=48662 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=34414 pr=850 pw=0 time=9746606 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=25 cnt=33338 pid=24 pos=1 obj=48664 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=9987 pr=5 pw=0 time=67429 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=26 cnt=7896 pid=23 pos=2 obj=94507 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0022056 (cr=59658 pr=625 pw=0 time=2693326 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=27 cnt=8429 pid=2 pos=2 obj=0 op='VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=421611 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16205841 us cost=1 size=3 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=28 cnt=8429 pid=27 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=421611 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16196537 us cost=4 size=6 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=29 cnt=8429 pid=28 pos=1 obj=0 op='NESTED LOOPS  (cr=421597 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16165037 us cost=3 size=20 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=30 cnt=368542 pid=29 pos=1 obj=48662 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=136832 pr=410 pw=0 time=1367514 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=31 cnt=368542 pid=30 pos=1 obj=48664 op='INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=11961 pr=3 pw=0 time=307670 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=32 cnt=8429 pid=29 pos=2 obj=83994 op='TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_207004AH (cr=284765 pr=2054 pw=0 time=13222238 us cost=1 size=10 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=33 cnt=8429 pid=32 pos=1 obj=83995 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0018436 (cr=276275 pr=691 pw=0 time=4370618 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)'
           STAT #4860378880 id=34 cnt=0 pid=28 pos=2 obj=48563 op='INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=14 pr=0 pw=0 time=15922 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)'
           FETCH #4860378880:c=1,e=1,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=0,og=0,plh=2750632795,tim=14609986053747
           *** SESSION ID:(596.44464) 2018-02-09 19:04:09.930
```

And TRACE.OUT contains:

```
 call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
    ------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
    Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
    Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
    Fetch        2      1.21      56.78      12055     588614          0           1
    ------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
    total        4      1.21      56.78      12055     588614          0           1

    Misses in library cache during parse: 0
    Optimizer mode: FIRST_ROWS
    Parsing user id: 51  
    Number of plan statistics captured: 1

    Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
    ---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
             1          1          1  SORT AGGREGATE (cr=588614 pr=12055 pw=0 time=56786438 us)
         10719      10719      10719   NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=588614 pr=12055 pw=0 time=56673159 us cost=9 size=60129541948 card=14)
         10719      10719      10719    NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=167003 pr=9591 pw=0 time=37387310 us cost=8 size=60129542102 card=14)
          6372       6372       6372     NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=72931 pr=8116 pw=0 time=36748544 us cost=7 size=56 card=14)
          5304       5304       5304      VIEW  (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10981326 us cost=8 size=182 card=14)
          5304       5304       5304       FILTER  (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10979429 us)
         15434      15434      15434        CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING (cr=19730 pr=4341 pw=0 time=10958416 us)
             1          1          1         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_PUBLICOBJECT (cr=4 pr=3 pw=0 time=21937 us cost=2 size=27 card=1)
             1          1          1          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=3 pr=2 pw=0 time=15438 us cost=2 size=0 card=1)(object id 48563)
         15433      15433      15433         NESTED LOOPS  (cr=19726 pr=4338 pw=0 time=5586309 us cost=4 size=364 card=13)
         15434      15434      15434          CONNECT BY PUMP  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=12493 us)
         15433      15433      15433          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_PUBLICOBJECT (cr=19726 pr=4338 pw=0 time=12094807 us cost=2 size=351 card=13)
         15433      15433      15433           INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_288_UNI (cr=14576 pr=1323 pw=0 time=3902935 us cost=1 size=0 card=13)(object id 295311)
          3158       3158       3158      VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=53201 pr=3775 pw=0 time=20327698 us cost=1 size=5 card=1)
          3158       3158       3158       NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=53201 pr=3775 pw=0 time=20323411 us cost=4 size=10 card=2)
          3158       3158       3158        NESTED LOOPS  (cr=50007 pr=3754 pw=0 time=22060978 us cost=3 size=24 card=2)
         17036      17036      17036         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=18986 pr=2822 pw=0 time=18693902 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)
         17036      17036      17036          INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=8328 pr=1107 pw=0 time=5986284 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)(object id 48664)
          3158       3158       3158         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_207214AH (cr=31021 pr=932 pw=0 time=5870949 us cost=1 size=12 card=1)
          3158       3158       3158          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0018438 (cr=27863 pr=587 pw=0 time=3262235 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 84011)
          3140       3140       3140        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=3194 pr=21 pw=0 time=197833 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)(object id 48563)
          7896       7896       7896     VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=94072 pr=1475 pw=0 time=6836424 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)
          7896       7896       7896      NESTED LOOPS  (cr=94072 pr=1475 pw=0 time=6829410 us cost=3 size=14 card=2)
         33338      33338      33338       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=34414 pr=850 pw=0 time=9746606 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)
         33338      33338      33338        INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=9987 pr=5 pw=0 time=67429 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)(object id 48664)
          7896       7896       7896       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0022056 (cr=59658 pr=625 pw=0 time=2693326 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)(object id 94507)
          8429       8429       8429    VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE  (cr=421611 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16205841 us cost=1 size=3 card=1)
          8429       8429       8429     NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=421611 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16196537 us cost=4 size=6 card=2)
          8429       8429       8429      NESTED LOOPS  (cr=421597 pr=2464 pw=0 time=16165037 us cost=3 size=20 card=2)
        368542     368542     368542       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED ODM_CATEGORY (cr=136832 pr=410 pw=0 time=1367514 us cost=2 size=28 card=2)
        368542     368542     368542        INDEX RANGE SCAN ODMI_331_UNI (cr=11961 pr=3 pw=0 time=307670 us cost=2 size=0 card=2)(object id 48664)
          8429       8429       8429       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID ODM_207004AH (cr=284765 pr=2054 pw=0 time=13222238 us cost=1 size=10 card=1)
          8429       8429       8429        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C0018436 (cr=276275 pr=691 pw=0 time=4370618 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 83995)
             0          0          0      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN SYS_C004488 (cr=14 pr=0 pw=0 time=15922 us cost=1 size=7 card=1)(object id 48563)

    ********************************************************************************
```